# Proving the Inclusion-Exclusion Formula?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been given the following problem:

```
Prove the inclusion-exclusion formula (it’s an extension of the subtraction rule)
|A ∪ B ∪ C| =|A| + |B| + |C| − |A ∩ B| − |A ∩ C| − |B ∩ C| + |A ∩ B ∩ C|.

To do the proof, let’s denote X = A ∪ B, then
|(A ∪ B) ∪ C| = |X ∪ C|,
and we can apply the usual subtraction rule (you will have to apply it twice)
```

My intuition is that that |X ∪ C| would equal |X| + |C| - |X ∩ C| (but this wouldn't account for the intersection of A and B which comprise X, which should also be subtracted, right?). I feel like this is almost self-evident and I'm not sure exactly how I'm supposed to argue this 'proof.' I almost want to use ven diagrams. Any thoughts?

Comment: This could be proved satisfactorily with a sequence of Venn diagrams.

Comment: Interestingly, Venn diagrams do not constitute a proof.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the usual subtraction rule?"

Comment: Your intuition is correct.  I'm assuming you are expected to know this and this is "the usual subtraction rule".  To prove this directly ....  oh, I'll write an answer.

Comment: @probablyme Venn diagrams may very well uniquely describe a linguistic proof and hence be sufficient as proof themselves. What is a proof, really? In formal logic it's well defined, but in everyday mathematical discourse it's just a bunch of words to convince your reader that you're right. In certain cases pictures may be sufficient.

Comment: @MattSamuel I agree. I use Venn diagrams to convince students conceptually about probability and stuff during tutoring hours. But I was thinking more along the lines of a typical class. Usually instructors want you to write down some convincing math as "proof". I can imagine telling this to my instructors and them laughing in my face. Hahaha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now use that $|X|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ and $|X\cap C|=|(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)|=|A\cap C|+|B\cap C|-|(A\cap C)\cap(B\cap C)|$

Answer (score 1):

$|X \cup U| = |X| + |U|- |X \cup U|$ is "the standard subtraction rule".

To prove this note: $ X \cup U = (X - (X\cap U)) + (U - (X \cap U)) + (X \cap U)$

These three sets-- $ (X - (X\cap U)) $, $ (U - (X \cap U)) $ and $ (X \cap U) $-- are disjoint. So $|X \cup U| =| | + | | + | |= (|X| - |X \cap U|) +(|U|-| (X \cap U)|) +(| (X \cap U)|)=|X|+|U| - |X \cap U|$. Done.

This proof relies upon knowing that if $A$ and $B$ are finite disjoint sets then $|A \cup B|= |A| +|B|$ which can be made clear simply by counting elements.  And if $A \subset B $ then $|B-A| = |B| - |A|$ again made clear by counting elements.

If sets are infinite then these rules may or may not hold.